# How do I notify my app that it's receiving cached responses from a service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I want to use a service worker to cache responses that can be used when the user is either offline or the my app's backend is down. For user experience reasons, I'd like to show a notification to the user that the app's backend currently can't be reached and that cached content is being served instead. What's the best way to do that? I can add a header to the response in the service worker but I'm not sure that's the "right way"... it seems like there should be a more straight-forward pattern. This is my service worker code:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  console.log(`fetch event`, event);
  event.respondWith(doFetch(event.request));
});

// fetch from network, fallback to cache
function doFetch(request) {
  return fetch(request)
    .then(response => {
      return caches.open(CACHE)
        .then(cache => {
          cache.put(request, response.clone());
          return response;
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.warn(`fetch to ${request.url} failed`, error);
      return fromCache(request);
    });
}

function fromCache(request) {
  return caches.open(CACHE)
    .then(cache => cache.match(request))
    .then(match => {
      if (match) {
        // response.clone doesn't work here because I need to modify it
        return cloneResponse(match);
      } else {
        throw new Error(`no match for ${request.url}`);
      }
    });
}
// this clones a response in a way that let's me modify it
function cloneResponse(response) {
  let init = {
    status: response.status,
    statusText: response.statusText,
    headers: { 'X-From-SW-Cache': 'true' }
  };

  response.headers.forEach((v, k) => {
    init.headers[k] = v;
  });

  return response.text().then((body) => new Response(body, init));
}
```

Comment: @Taplar That doesn't work actually. It throws "Failed to construct 'Response': Response with null body status cannot have body", which makes sense. 304 responses are empty by definition.

Comment: Adding a header sounds totally fine.

Comment: @Bergi After thinking about it more -- I think ideally the backend would return a Date header on all responses, but if that's not possible, then you've got to modify the response and add a header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a header to the response is definitely one option.

Another option to consider is to use [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Client/postMessage) to send a message to the client page letting it know that a cached response is being used. You could extend that logic to also send a message to the client letting it know when a network response is used, if you want to toggle some UI element once you're back to using the network.

Here's the code to accomplish that in your service worker:

```js
async function postToClient(clientId, message) {
  const client = await clients.get(clientId);
  client.postMessage(message);
}

async function responseLogic(event) {
  const cache = await caches.open('cache-name');
  try {
    const response = await fetch(event.request);
    await cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
    event.waitUntil(postToClient(event.request.clientId, 'FROM_NETWORK'));
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request);
    if (cachedResponse) {
      event.waitUntil(postToClient(event.request.clientId, 'FROM_CACHE'));
      return cachedResponse;
    }
    throw error;
  }
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  // Check to see if this is a request for your API:
  if (event.request.url === 'https://example.com/api') {
    event.respondWith(responseLogic(event));
  }
});
```

And then on your client page, you can register a `message` listener to respond to those messages from the service worker by showing or hiding some UI element, depending on whether the last response came from the network or cache:

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  if (event.data === 'FROM_NETWORK') {
    // Do something in your UI.
  } else if (event.data === 'FROM_CACHE') {
    // Do something in your UI.
  }
});
```